# Safari does not go back to Google when search was issued in URL line

Tags: safari, search

I enter some search words in the URL line of Safari. Upon pressing ENTER, I get the Google search result page. I click on one of the search results and of course, Safari takes me to that page. Everything as usual, nothing special so far.

BUT now, when I hit de "Back" button in Safari, it won't take me back to the google search, but to the last other page visited in that tab. So that means, when checking out multiple results, I always have to repeat the search. Very annoying.

**How can I configure Safari to take me back to the search results when hitting "Back"?**

I use Safari 10.1.1 on a Mac Book Pro with macOS Sierra 10.12.5.

Comment: Hi Michael, it may be worth you clarifying whether you're talking about Safari on a Mac, an iPhone, etc? And also what version of Safari and the OS you're using?

Comment: This still exists in Safari 11. No longer going to use it.